# Does Microsoft Live Office allow me to curl a site and write the output into a cell?

Tags: excel, office365

This is my current test excel sheet in [Microsoft Live Office](https://onedrive.live.com/):

```
product name    price when purchase     price now   diff        profit/loss
P1              10000                   12000       =b2-a2      =c2*70/100
P2              12000                   14000       =b3-a3      =c3*70/100
P3              8000                    10000       =b4-a4      =c4*70/100
```

Now I manually edit the prices of `B` column, but what I'm looking for is:

> `curl -sL website.com | grep P1 | grep price` and then write that into `price now` column automatically

Is that possible to do in Live Office?

The time period of checking `website.com` can, for example once a day.